# Spivak Chapter 11 Question 39

Tags: real-analysis

> (a) Prove that if $f$ is a twice differentiable function with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$ and $f'(0) = f'(1) = 0$, then $|f''(x)| \geq 4$ for some $x$ in $[0,1]$.
>
> Hint: Prove that either $f''(x) > 4$ for some $x$ in $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$, or else $f''(x) < -4$ for some $x$ in $[\frac{1}{2},1]$.
>
> (b) Show that in fact we must have $|f''(x)| > 4$ for some $x$ in $[0,1]$.

This question is from Spivak's Calculus, Chapter 11 question 39.  There is duplicate question but it seems to use integration which is not taught by Chapter 11 (on derivatives and related theorems).  It also seems the Answers book for Spivak's calculus has an error, or not is explained properly, it says: "$ f(x)<4x^2$ implies $ f(1/2)<1/2 $".

Comment: It should be $\;f(x)<2x^2$ implies… This results from *Taylor-Lagrange's inequality* if $|f''(x)|<4$.

Comment: The answers book should indeed read "$f(x) < 2x^2$ implies $f(1/2) < 1/2$", which is not hard to verify by inserting $x=1/2$ and you should note that $2x^2$ has the critical second derivative of $4$.

To solve (a) without integration you just need to apply the mean value theorem twice. First to show that $f''(x) < 4$ implies $f'(x) < 4x$ and then that this implies $f(x) < 2x^2$  Part (b) should then be clear by closely looking at the argument for (a).

Comment: @Bernard  Sorry what is Taylor-Lagrange's inequality?  Can't seem to find it,

Comment: @mlk How does the second application of mean value theorem give you $f(x)<2x^2$ though?

Comment: Consider $g(x) = f(x)-2x^2$. Then $g'(x) =f'(x)-4x < 0$. From this, per mean value theorem $g(x) <0$ and thus $f(x) < 2x^2$.

Comment: @mlk one more issue relating to the answer in (b).  At about halfway it says "and consequently for all larger x"  in referring to $f'(x)<4x$.  But what is the basis for this?  I can see why does leads do the conclusion we want but not the reason.

Comment: It's the estimation of the remainder deduced from Taylor-Lagrange's formula when you know the derivative of order $n+1$ is bounded on the interval.

Answer (score 0):

If $|f''(x)|<4$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ then

(1). There exists $y\in [0,1/2]$ such that  $f(1/2)=f(0)+(1/2)f'(0)+(1/2)^2f''(y)/2=(1/2)^2f''(y)/2=f''(y)/8 <4/8=1/2.$

and

(2). There exists $z\in [1/2,1]$ such that $f(1/2)=f(1)+(1/2-1)f'(1)+(1/2-1)^2f''(z)/2= 1+f''(z)/8>1-4/8=1/2.$

Comment: What theorem is used to get your equation $f(1/2)=f(0)+(1/2)f'(0)+(1/2)^2f''(y)/2=(1/2)^2f''(y)/2=f''(y)/8 <4/8=1/2$?

Comment: The generalized MVT, also known as a remainder formula for a power series.  It should be in the book. I assume it has a section on power series.